# What is default location of ChromeDriver and for installing Chrome on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to install `chromedriver` on Windows OS. In the article below they specify:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

> "...ChromeDriver expects you to have Chrome installed in the default
>   location for your platform..."

But I'm not sure what is the default location ?

On **Mac** OS it's `/usr/local/bin`.

With this I don't have to specify path explicitly or setup system path either.

How to achieve the same on Windows OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any driver that Selenium must use to open the browser (`chromedriver`, `geckodriver`, etc), you don't have to worry about where it is installed, as long as it's set in the `PATH` variable.

If you have it set in the OS `PATH` variable, you must be able to run it from the `command` or `cmd` (it's always good to make sure it's working).

Here's how you can set it (append to the existing value):

- Article: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm
- Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz59GsdvUF8

Then you can just instantiate it as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

OR

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Hope it's somehow helpful.

Comment: Thanks to your youtube video link, I figured out that I need to put chromedriver under c:\program files\any_folder. But this path I need to mention under PATH, still it didn't solve my query why can't Windows know about chromedriver put under c:\program files , why I need to explicitly mention that path under PATH ? With Mac/ Ubuntu if I just put under /user/local/bin, chromedriver works fine

Comment: On Mac/Ubuntu it works fine, because `/usr/local/bin` is in the PATH (`usr` is a short to User System Resources, not user). To check that, open a terminal in a Linux/Mac and type `env | grep PATH` to check it is there. So, in Linux/Mac, when you install/copy to `/usr/local/bin`, you're already installing in a folder seen by the PATH variable. I'm not sure the command `env` works on Windows, but you can still run `echo %PATH%` to show all the directories listed by it.

Comment: This solution is no longer valid.  Even if chromedriver.exe is on the path, you will get this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 29):

These are two interrelated important questions as follows :

- Default location of **ChromeDriver**
- Default location of **Chromium/Google Chrome**

### ChromeDriver

You can download the recently released **ChromeDriver** from [**ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) page and place it any where within your system. When you initialize the *ChromeDriver* you need to pass the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* binary.

Additionally, you can also help *WebDriver* to locate the downloaded *ChromeDriver* executable through the following steps :

- Include the *ChromeDriver* location in your system **PATH** environment variable.
- (*Java*) Specify the location of *ChromeDriver* through the `webdriver.chrome.driver` *system property*
- (*Python*) Specify the location of *ChromeDriver* when instantiating `webdriver.Chrome()`

### Chromium/Google Chrome

The most important fact is you need to ensure that **Chromium/Google Chrome** is installed in a recognized location as per the [**ChromeDriver - Requirements**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements) as the server expects you to have **Chromium/Google Chrome** installed in the default location for each system as per the snapshot:

[image: ChromeDriver - Requirements]

**Note** : For Linux systems, the *ChromeDriver* expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a *symlink* to the actual **Chrome binary**. You can also override the *Chrome binary location* following [**Using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location) .

### Sample Code Block

- *Java* :

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

  public class A_Chrome 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          // Optional : if not specified WebDriver will search your system PATH environment variable for locating the chromedriver
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- *Python* :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  # Optional argument : if not specified WebDriver will search your system PATH environment variable for locating the chromedriver
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395499/errormessagespawn-opt-chromedriver-chromedriver-enoent

Answer (score 2):

Default  location on Windows is: `C:\Program Files\(select the folder you want to put your file)\chromedriver.exe`

In your Selenium code, paste the driver path correctly, for example:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: If I don't want to hard code that path value in program, is there any alternative ? In Mac OS, if I don't have to do all these workaround as it knows default location

Comment: Try pasting the "chromedriver.exe" file inside the selenium file (selenium installation files) . Hope it works

Comment: I' m not sure what do u mean by default location for installing. Anyhow it is not installing it';s just u r downloading and keeping a copy of file.

If you dont want to hard code the location keep the chromedriver.exe file in prj root dir and use System.getProperty("user.dir") and append chromedriver.exe to make it relative path

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that I need to put chromedriver under c:\program files\any_folder. But this path I need to mention under PATH, still it didn't solve my query why can't Windows know about chromedriver put under c:\program files , why I need to explicitly mention that path under PATH ? With Mac/ Ubuntu if I just put under /user/local/bin, chromedriver works fine

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Python virtual environment with 'virtualenv'. You can drop the chromedriver.exe in your virtual environment's bin/ directory.

```
> virtual venv
> cd Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver(.exe) working/directory/path/venv/bin/
```

Then try running the Python script with the virtual env's interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

## Download the standalone package and link to it.

I have found that to download the package to your desktop and to point to it in your program is just the simplest and easiest solution

[I found a link for the standalone package here.](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=111.0.5563.64/)

You can then point to the package with a little bit of code like the following.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome("The-Path-To-The-Web-Driver")
```

Answer (score 0):

My chromedriver package was installed in my Python folder. If I remember correctly, I installed it with pip. The strange thing is that the chromedriver folder did not contain the chromedriver.exe file, which I had to download and move to the site-packages folder separately.

```
C:\\Users\\_USERNAME_\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\chromedriver
```

(I use double \:s in the path because a single \ plus the letter U (in C:-->**\U**<--sers...) would result in

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

)