# Selenium with python script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to selenium and I keep running into the same error. I'm working on a windows os and have selenium version is v4.6.0.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/')
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

But I keep running into this error and the path for the driver is correct.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chris\development\automation\selenium\index.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\chris\development\automation\selenium\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\chris\development\automation\selenium\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
    ignore_proxy=self.options._ignore_local_proxy,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795348/8669719    the webdriver.Chrome(absolute_path_to_chromedriver.exe) needs the absolute path to the chromedriver. See answer for detailed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the below line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
```

If your selenium version is `v4.6.0` or above, then you don't need to set the path for `chromedriver.exe`, so your code can be simplified as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/')
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76574264/7598774
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774
- [Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

Answer (score 1):

You need an absolute path to chrome driver for selenium to work.
Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795348/8669719).

Answer (score 0):

Note: Remove `executable_url` from the argument, because you have installed the latest **version** of **Selenium** if you have selenium above the `4.6.0` you don't need to add `executable_url` and in the latest version of **Selenium** you don't need to download **webdriver**.

**just copy the below code and run the your python file simple**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```